# Bend a div with CSS

Tags: css, webkit

Is it possible to bend a div with CSS?

Some sort of webkit transform...

The effect i want to create is a have a ring doughnut shape but made up of a curved div as opposed to border-radius/border tricks

EDIT:

Use case - I'd like to put a linear gradient on this div and have the gradient wrap back around on itself, like in the game Snake, where it chases it tail...

Comment: What else are you doing with it that you can't just use border-radius?

Comment: Show a picture of what you want?

Comment: By bend do you mean you want text to curve?  Then, this is not possible afaik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible with CSS alone. Your best bet would be to make use of the `canvas` (and some Javascript).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

http://www.roblaplaca.com/examples/bezierBuilder/

**Update August 2023:**

This still isn't possible with only CSS (happy to be proven wrong). There are some interesting things you can do though, but they all depend on border, border radius, etc.

References:

- [Client-side Web API for drawing graphics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Drawing_graphics)
- [The Shape of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)

Comment: The first link page seems to be removed from MDN

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can without using the border-radius trick:

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

The border-radius trick is the one that I like,

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/ea3An/

Comment: The w3schools link seems to be removed from their site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want text to curve, then this is a problem made for SVG's [Text on a Path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/SVG/TEXT_PATH/TextPath.html) capability. (or Canvas). Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clip-path property of css putting polygon in value and make points as you want to change the shape of div

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I recommend using **THREE.js** and the **HTML5 canvas tag**. You can easily bend and animate with it. Check out the examples. Have Fun!

[THREE.js Examples](http://threejs.org/)