# How to bend a div in CSS

Tags: css

I need some help with some css I am playing around.
How can I bend a div with css to achieve something like in the image below.
I need to blue filled divs which are curved.

[image]

Comment: Play with `border-radius`.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/8528165/1482033

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla: Already seen this. didn't helped

Comment: what have you tried yet then ?

Comment: @torazaburo: No luck with border-radius. I can only shape a full circle

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla: I have played around with border radius. But this gives me a circle or donut

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17040896/1482033

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar effect can be achieved using two `div`s and CSS:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgJQgN

```css
#c {
  height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#b {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 30px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```