# CSS Curved Button

Tags: html, css, styling

I need an outline of a button that is curved on the top and bottom, but not the sides. See the Sample Image below to understand what I'm asking for. I will style all the buttons on my website like this one. I've tried a few ways of doing this with border-radius but I haven't been successful yet. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bend a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528165/bend-a-div-with-css)

Comment: This is not currently possible in pure CSS, you'll need SVG used either as a clip-path or directly: https://jsfiddle.net/wphpa59n/

Comment: Something I was playing with (its not pretty).. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/cojoocn4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not the answer that you expected, but I think that the best way to get this result (being the easiest way to get decent results) is with a `backgroung-image`.

```
.button {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dknacht/GitHub-Test/master/rect4136.png); 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

I just post it in case that someone with similar needs wants to have an alternative.

here an example: https://codepen.io/dknacht/pen/qKbWaY

Dknacht.

Comment: A background image worked best. Even though I couldn't do it with pure CSS, this method seemed to work best.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:before` and `:after` to button

```css
.btn {
  border-top:none;
  border-bottom:none;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white ;
  background-color: #273649;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
body{
  background-color: #273649;
}
.btn:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 89px;
    height: 16px;
    border-top: white 2px solid;
    top: 48px;
    left: 7px;
    border-radius: 40%;
}
.btn:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 89px;
    height: 16px;
    border-top: white 2px solid;
    top: 4px;
    left: 7px;
    border-radius: 40%;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Info</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the corners look strange. I've ended up using an SVG as a background image to achieve the look I was going for.